# Como eliminar tabla padre y que automáticamente lo hagan los hijos en mysql (DELETE ON CASCADE)

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

Ando con una duda.

¿Existe alguna forma en MySQL de que al eliminar una fila en la tabla padre automáticamente las tablas que tengan registros que referencien a las mismas a través de foráneas se eliminen automáticamente?

Actualmente tengo 3 tablas, 1 padre y 2 hijos y tienen como constraint en la foráneas que referencia al padre MATCH SIMPLE ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE pero me he dado cuenta que para eliminar la tabla padre a juro debo eliminar los hijos primero para poder eliminar esta.

¿Hay alguna forma de que sea al contrario y que sea automático?

Ejemplo: Tengo la clase estante y la clase libro y quiero que si elimino una fila en la tabla estante todos los registros en libro que referencien a ese estante se eliminen también en vez de tener que eliminar primero todos los libros que referencian a ese estante para luego eliminar el estante como tal.

Es una pregunta que no es necesaria para una tabla en específico sino para la situación como tal indiferentemente de la tabla y los datos que tengan, solo importa la relación de la foránea con la clave principal y el hecho que elimine como mencioné anteriormente.

Cualquier ayuda es agradecida. Muchas gracias!

Comment: con eliminar la tabla padre te refieres a un `DROP TABLE` ? o a borrar una fila de la tabla padre?

Comment: Mira [ask] <- ACA para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] <- ACA para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Tomando como referencia mi ejemplo, me refería a un DELETE FROM Estante Where LI_ID = x siendo x un número, y que al hacer esto elimine a los hijos y luego al padre a través de constraints o algún otro método, porque de contrario hay que eliminar uno por uno los hijos que refieran al padre para luego eliminarlo a el. Capaz es con un trigger pero de resto lo ando ejecutando así y siento que podría ser mas eficiente si pudiera lograr esto.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La idea de la **Integridad Referencial** es precisamente prevenir comportamiento inesperado.

Tu caso en específico se maneja a través de CASCADE, tanto para el delete como para el update; de tal modo que la lógica indica que el proceso es que si el id de un usuario que es llave primaria es a su vez utilizada como llave foránea en la tabla posts; no se puede eliminar un usuario pues esta vinculada su información.

Lo correcto en estos casos es seguir precisamente ese patrón finalmente te dará el mismo resultado al final; ya que cuando declaras un **CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY**; estás declarando que ese valor se sujetará a: **CASCADE, SET NULL, NO ACTION, ETC**

1. **RESTRICT** -> Por defecto el motor de bases de datos no te dejará hacer modificaciones que atenten o dañen la integridad y consistencia de la información
2. **CASCADE** -> Como en el ejemplo de users y posts, solo te va a eliminar el post relacionado cuando el registro principal, es decir el id del usuario que lo creo ya no exista
3. **SET NULL** -> Me ayudará a por ejemplo que cuando se elimine el registro conserve ese espacio pero se muestre como **NULO**

¿Entonces por qué me deja eliminar de la tabla donde la llave primaria se vuelve llave foránea?

Bueno precisamente te lo permite por que esa llave ahí no es un valor primario si no una integridad referencial a otra tabla

La anterior explicación ocurre también para el caso de querer eliminar una tabla.

Para el ejemplo tal cual de una tabla usuarios y una tabla posts, donde en la tabla posts se almacenará el id del usuario como llave foránea; si se pudiera hacer lo que deseas en este caso eliminar la tabla padre llamada users, mi tabla posts quedaría así:

id    titulo     user_id     status
1     post 1     NULL          1
2     post 2     NULL          0

> Se pierde la consistencia de la base de datos, ya que es una tabla
>   secundaria que su propia definición y contexto depende de una tabla
>   padre o principal, con lo cual pierde su propio valor como una entidad
>   en tu base de datos

Espero sea de utilidad la explicación

Answer (score 0):

No hay una forma directa de borrar una tabla padre que tenga deletes o updates en cascada.

Varias opciones segun lo que pretendas obtener como resultado final

**1** desactivar el check de foreign keys

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
DROP TABLE tabla_padre;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
```

Nota: las tablas_hijo quedaran con indices apuntando cosas que no existen

**2** averiguar que tablas hijo tienen referencias a tabla_padre y remover las referencias

```
SELECT * 
FROM information_schema.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE 
WHERE REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME = 'tabla_padre';
```

luego por cada tabla_hijo que tiene una foránea

```
ALTER TABLE 'tabla_hijo' 
DROP FOREIGN KEY 'la_clave_foranea';
```

Nota: si `la_clave_foranea` es parte de otro índice va a desaparecer de ahí también, esto puede llegar a dejar dos (o mas) índices iguales.
Ejemplo

```
indice1 = la_clave_foranea
indice2 = la_clave_foranea, nombre, apellido
indice3 = nombre, apellido
```

si desaparece `la_clave_foranea`, `indice1` no existe mas, pero ahora tenes dos índices iguales: `indice2` e `indice3`

Hay otras variantes que juegan con cambiar la constricción (por ejemplo `ON DELETE SET NULL`) pero dependerá de como quieras continuar con la base de datos.

TL;DR: para borrar todas las tablas padres e hijos usa la opcion 1